# how to check if a non primitive java array has a certain element

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm trying to search a java array that has values of a class called Tickets has a certain ticket object...the usual for loop with if statements used for primitive data types does not work

I have tried the stuff below

```
public  Ticket retrieve(String ticketID){
    Ticket retur;
    for(int i=0;i<numTickets;i++){
        if (tickets[i].equals(ticketID)){
        retur = tickets[i];
        }
    } 
    return retur;
}
```

I'm getting the error retur may not be initialised.

Comment: What will happen in your app if `numTickets` will be `0` or none of the tickets will be equal to `ticketID`? Then function will return uninitialized value. Simple fix would be to add `retur = null`, but you have to consider rest of your code (which I don't know).

Comment: For an immediate fix, use `Ticket retur = null`, when you declare this variable.

Comment: when using a variable, the compiler checks if it has been initialized, or better, if it may not have been initialized (on any *apparent* branch the code may take) - if so, you'll get that message. This is not related to using "primitive data" or not. It is a good indication that something is missing/wrong with the implemented logic (here missing what to return or do if nothing was found)

Comment: ok I think If you can help me with how to search a nonprimitive valued array for a certain object that would help

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize `Ticket` object because if your array don't have any object with same ticketId then your `Ticket` oibject remain uninitialized. Your Comparison is also wrong. you have to compare `ticketId` with some field of `Ticket` object. like `tickets[i].getId().equals(ticketID)`

```
public Ticket retrieve(String ticketID){
        for(int i=0;i<numTickets;i++){
            if (tickets[i].equals(ticketID)){
               return tickets[i];//If tickets[i] is a `String` object then you have to convert it into `Ticket` object before returning. Or if `tickets[i]` is a `Ticket` object then you comparison is wrong.
            }
        } 
        return null;
 }
```

Comment: just a note: but this is changing the actual logic: returning the first found element instead of the last (no idea if that was intentional by OP). And, by question, be can only assume that `tickets` is `Ticket[]`, so comparing it to `String` should fail, again assuming that `equals` implementation follows the `equals` contract